# Classic ASP passing array to a function

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

In classic ASP I need to extract data out of a MSSQL database, passing the results to a two dimensional array (rows, columns) and display the data in various formats.

For each such format I need to build functions to display data. So, in order to be as modular as possible I need to separate (i) extraction and passing data to the array from (ii) displaying the results.

My code does currently the extraction of data using a class, but also displays (within the same class) the data in a primitive way (just to test that the data is extracted and correct).
How can I pass such array to a function? You can imagine how flexible would be to have an array as data input into a function and then manipulate it (creating many functions) when trying to display it in a table (example: function 1 will be based on template no. 1 of a table that is red with background black and no borderline, function 2 is built on the template 2, the table is green, with borderline and yellow background, etc etc).

Here is my code and at the end of the main function (within the class) you will see a portion that displays results, i.e. the one that I need to do it separately from / outside the class (i.e. in the functions to be created).

```
<!--#include file ="../functions/fctGetnrofrecords.asp"-->
<%

Dim db : Set db = New GetRowsFromAdatabase
db.strTable="Customers"
strDisplay=db.FindOutRecordsAndPassThemToAnArray()

Response.Write strDisplay

Class GetRowsFromAdatabase

Public strTable
Public numberOfRecords
Public numberOfFields

Public Function FindOutRecordsAndPassThemToAnArray()

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Find out connecting credentials
  strSERVERspecific=Coli(0)
  strDATABASENAMEspecific=Coli(1)
  strUIDspecific=Coli(2)
  strPWDspecific=Coli(3)

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=" & strSERVERspecific & ";database=" & strDATABASENAMEspecific & ";uid=" & strUIDspecific & ";pwd=" & strPWDspecific & ";"

rs.Open strTable, conn

            if rs.EOF and rs.BOF then
                    strError = "There is no record in the table " & strTable
            else
                    'Assign the Number Of Fields to the variable “counter”
                    counter = rs.fields.count
                   numberOfFields=counter

                    Dim matrix(25, 10) ' these exceed by far the values of numberOfRecords and numberOfFields

                    for j=0 to counter-1
                         matrix(0,j)= rs.Fields(j).Name ' The first dimension of the array, when is zero,
                                                        ' is populated with the names of fields
                    next

                    rs.movefirst
                    i=1
                    do until rs.EOF

                            for j=0 to counter-1
                                    matrix(i,j)=rs(j)
                            next
                    i=i+1
                    rs.movenext
                    loop
            end if

' Now, I need this class not to include the displaying section that follows
' (i.e. see the portion until the end of this function), although this section works fine

numberOfRecords=fctGetNumberOfRowsOfaTable(strTable) 
'see the include directive at the beginning of this code (there is a function there that does this)

'====begin section that displays the arrays values
for m = 0 to numberOfRecords
  for n=0 to counter-1
         strDisplay = strDisplay & m & "," & n & "=" & matrix(m,n) & "<br>"
  next
next
'====end section that displays the array values

FindOutRecordsAndPassThemToAnArray = strDisplay

End Function



Public Function Coli(x)

'This function read a line of a txt file located on the server side (hidden from public / httpdocs)

' where x =  the relevant line out of the following
                    ' 1 means the 1st line = name / IP server
                    ' 2 means the 2nd line = database name
                    ' 3 means the 3rd line = user name available in the database
                    ' 4 means the 4th line = user’s password

if x<0 or x> 3 then
  Coli="Erorr"
  Exit Function
else

serv=Server.MapPath("../../../")
path=serv & "\somehiddenfolder\"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path & "configuration.txt")

J=0
Dim Datele(3)
   Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
   strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline

   if x=J then
      Coli=strNextLine
      exit function
   else
      J=J+1
   end if
Loop
end if
End Function

End Class

%>
```

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.GetRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an array of a table/resultset. To pass such an array to a function (why function? what should be its return value?) you write its name in the argument list of the function call.

**Update wrt comment:**

Sample of calling a function that expects an array:

```
>> Function sum(a)
>>   sum = Join(a, "+")
>> End Function
>> a = Split("1 2 3")
>> WScript.Echo sum(a)
>>
1+2+3
```

Instead of Split() - which returns a one dimensional array - you'd use .GetRows() on a valid recordset (and keep in mind that .GetRows() returns a two dimensional array).

Comment: Its return value? I don't know, this was the thing that came to my mind just to do the displaying job. I am not expert to VBscript or ASP classic. Could you show some examples how I can do that? (I mean to write its name in the argument list of the function call, not how I can use GetRows).

Comment: I see. Well, I will try this and come back with the outcome. Anyway, your solution seems to match my needs. Thanks for the hint with GetRows.